# How do I group an SQL table by time stamps close to each other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by, sql-view

**I have a table of user activity:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.user_session_activity_table (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    "userId" integer NOT NULL,
    "creationDate" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO public.user_session_activity_table 
(
    id, 
    "userId",
    "creationDate"
) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, '2021-11-06 10:54:23.891327'),
    (2, 1, '2021-11-06 10:59:56.616956'),
    (3, 1, '2021-11-06 10:59:57.680751'),
    (4, 1, '2021-11-06 10:59:58.857336'),
    (5, 1, '2021-11-06 11:36:47.112812'),
    (6, 1, '2021-11-06 11:36:49.049485'),
    (7, 1, '2021-11-06 11:36:50.931315')
```

**Desired output:**

```
id  userId  sessionLenght
1   1       123s                 -- row 1 
2   1       123s                 -- row 2-4 grouped together
3   1       123s                 -- row 4-7 grouped together
```

**Explanation:**

I'm creating a view of user sessions, form a table that contains the row's of saved user activity. I'd like to GROUP BY on the time delta that elapses between creation dates. If too much time elapses (let's say the threshold is 1 minute) the current group ends and a new one starts. This would result this sample data to be aligned to 3 groups:

- id:1
- id:2, id:3, id:4
- id:5, id:6, id:7

As you can see, the most significant time difference is between id:1 <-> id:2 and id:4 <-> id:5, that's why it should breaks into 3 separate groups.

I'm using the latest version of PostgreSQL. The "sessionLength" is not quite that important, I can find a solution for that myself, the main problem is creating these groups.

**One important fact is: rounding the date would't work, a session could last for several minutes, or hours. The thing that should end and begin groups is the time difference between activities (for example when a user is logged out, or away from keyboard for an hour).**

**Update 1:**

The window RANGE function is also not the solition. It was convincing at first, but it only groups together rows whithin a pre specified time frame.

[image]

```
SELECT 
*
FROM (
    SELECT
        "usa"."userId",
        "usa"."creationDate" AS "currentDate",
        FIRST_VALUE("usa"."creationDate") OVER www AS "sessionStartDate",
        LAST_VALUE("usa"."creationDate") OVER www AS "sessionEndDate"
    --  first_value("usa"."id") OVER www AS first_id, 
    --  last_value("usa"."id") OVER www AS last_id, 
--      LAST_VALUE("usa"."creationDate") OVER www - FIRST_VALUE("usa"."creationDate") OVER www AS "sessionLength"
    FROM public."user_session_activity_view" AS "usa"
    WINDOW www AS 
    (
        PARTITION BY "userId"
        ORDER BY "creationDate"
        RANGE BETWEEN '3 min' PRECEDING AND '3 min' FOLLOWING
    ) 
) AS "sq"

WHERE "sq"."userId" = 33
    
ORDER BY
    "sq"."userId",
    "sq"."sessionStartDate"
```

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!
(please tell me if the question is unclear, I'll try to clarify it a bit more! :) )

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) link.

Comment: On it, I'll edit the Q in a bit.

Comment: @Stu edits are done.

Comment: Your **new** question is not clear. It also is not very polite to change a question if valid answers are already present. You should ask an other question. [I think the question should be rolled back to the original version]

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't give you a complete solution but it might help get you there, using row_number to identify rows to be grouped together in durations of 60 seconds:

```
with u as (
  select *,
    id - row_number() over (partition by userid, round(extract('epoch' from creationdate) / 60) * 60 order by creationdate) gp
  from t 
)
select 
  row_number() over(partition by max(userId) order by max(creationdate)) GroupNo,
  max(userid) UserId,
  min(creationdate) StartOfRange, max(CreationDate) EndOfRange,
  round(max(date_part('second',creationdate::time))- min(date_part('second',creationdate::time))) duration
from u
group by gp
```

Answer (score 1):

[window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-window.html) allow you to specyfy a [range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html). You can use that to get the first value and last value for the addressed set of records. [I needed the `omg` subquery to actually use the values (substract them) and to filter only the (pseudo-) aggregates. Just omit the `WHERE` clause to see how it works...]

---

```
SELECT
        first_id, user_id
        , ze_first, ze_last
        , (ze_last-ze_first) AS timespan
        , 1+(last_id -first_id) AS nrecords
FROM    (
        SELECT
        id, user_id
        , first_value(id) OVER www AS first_id
        , last_value(id) OVER www AS last_id
        , first_value(creation_date) OVER www AS ze_first
        , last_value(creation_date) OVER www AS ze_last
        FROM user_session_activity_table
                WINDOW www AS (
                        PARTITION BY user_id
                        ORDER BY creation_date
                        -- This is the magic ...
                        RANGE BETWEEN '1 min' PRECEDING AND '1 min' FOLLOWING
                        )
        ) omg
WHERE id=first_id -- anything goes ...
        ;
```

Comment: This is magic, thank you!

Comment: this is not working as expected. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: `... (let's say the threshold is 1 minute) ...`

Comment: To give a little more explanation about why this is not working as expected: The `WINDOW` function includes all rows within `RANGE` of the *current row*, it does not include rows recursively. E.g. When there is a row `B` 40 seconds after the current row and a row `C` 80 seconds after the current row, only the `B` row will be included despite the `C` row being within 1 minute of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

You need STRING_AGG function in postgresql;
some thing like,I am not familiar with postgresql

```
SELECT id,userId,STRING_agg(id,';'),to_char(creationDate, 'HH:MI') FROM public.user_session_activity_table

GROUP BY
    userId,to_char(creationDate, 'HH:MI')
```

Comment: In that case rounding up the date would work as well, sadly, the case is a user could be logged in for hours, that would count as one session. Imagine an entry here for 3 hourse every one minute.

Comment: how about using lag and lead function in order to get time stamps?

Comment: I was experimenting with them, eventually I got it working, but I have also received another answer here, which solves this more elegantly! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, it's VERY UGLY, but it gets the job done. As you can see I have used the LAG() function to deduce the start of a user session, and used another LAG() function in an outer query to deduce the start of a next session. Between these dates is the content of the group, which is joined afterwards. I hope this helps someone who stumbles upon this problem in the future. :)

As a side note, I'm still looking for better solutions, if anyone reads this.

```
SELECT 
    "usav"."userId" AS "userId",
    "groups_2"."groupStartDate" AS "sessionStartDate",
    MAX("usav"."creationDate") AS "sessionEndDate",
    MAX("usav"."creationDate") - "groups_2"."groupStartDate" AS "sessionLength",
    "u"."email" AS "userEmail"
FROM 
(
    -- group_2
    SELECT 
        "groups_1".*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER wind AS "groupId", 
        LAG ("groups_1"."groupStartDate", -1) OVER wind AS "nextGroupStartDate"
    FROM 
    (
        -- group_1
        SELECT * FROM 
        (
            -- sq
            SELECT
                "usav"."userId",
                "usav"."creationDate" AS "groupStartDate",
                LAG ("usav"."creationDate") OVER (
                    PARTITION BY "usav"."userId"
                    ORDER BY "usav"."creationDate") < "usav"."creationDate" - INTERVAL '5 min'
                IS DISTINCT FROM false AS "isGroupStart"
            FROM public."user_session_activity_view" AS "usav"
        ) AS "sq"

        WHERE "sq"."isGroupStart"

        ORDER BY
            "sq"."userId",
            "sq"."groupStartDate"
    ) AS "groups_1"
    
    WINDOW wind AS 
    (
        PARTITION BY "groups_1"."userId"
        ORDER BY "groups_1"."groupStartDate"
    )
) AS "groups_2"

LEFT JOIN public."user_session_activity_view" AS "usav"
ON "usav"."userId" = "groups_2"."userId"
    AND "usav"."creationDate" >= "groups_2"."groupStartDate"
    AND ("usav"."creationDate" < "groups_2"."nextGroupStartDate" 
         OR "groups_2"."nextGroupStartDate" IS NULL)
         
LEFT JOIN public."user" AS "u"
ON "u"."id" = "usav"."userId"
        
GROUP BY
    "usav"."userId",
    "groups_2"."groupStartDate",
    "u"."email"
    
ORDER BY
    "usav"."userId",
    "groups_2"."groupStartDate"
```

Comment: `... (let's say the threshold is 1 minute) ...`